# scjp: threads related issue

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify, scjp

below is the question...

```
void waitForSignal() {
     Object obj = new Object();
     synchronized (Thread.currentThread()) {
         obj.wait();
         obj.notify();
     }
 }
```

Which statement is true?

A. This code can throw an `InterruptedException`.

B. This code can throw an `IllegalMonitorStateException`.

C. This code can throw a `TimeoutException` after ten minutes.

D. Reversing the order of `obj.wait()` and `obj.notify()` might cause this method to complete normally.

E. A call to `notify()` or `notifyAll()` from another thread might cause this method to complete normally.

F. This code does NOT compile unless `obj.wait()` is replaced with `((Thread) obj).wait()`.

Answer is B . But when i have executed in below manner getting A. Please help.

```
public class ThreadStateProblem extends Thread {  
    public void run() {  

    }  

    void waitForSignal() {
        Object obj = new Object();
        synchronized (Thread.currentThread()) {
            obj.wait();
            obj.notify();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String []s) {  
        new ThreadStateProblem().start();  
        new ThreadStateProblem().waitForSignal();
    }    
}
```

And also tried below :

```
public class ThreadStateProblem extends Thread {  
    public void run() {  

    }  

    void waitForSignal() {
        Object obj = new Object();
        synchronized (Thread.currentThread()) {
            obj.wait();
            obj.notify();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String []s) {  
        ThreadStateProblem sd =new ThreadStateProblem();
        sd.start();
        sd.waitForSignal();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Why do you create two ThreadStateProblem objects? Because you call `start()` on one thread, and `waitForSignal()` on a different one.

Comment: just tried .......no specific reason.......also tried with same object......getting same....                                  public class ThreadStateProblem extends Thread {  
    public void run() {  

    }  

    void waitForSignal() {
        Object obj = new Object();
        synchronized (Thread.currentThread()) {
            obj.wait();
            obj.notify();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String []s) {  
        ThreadStateProblem sd =new ThreadStateProblem();
        sd.start();
        sd.waitForSignal();
    }    
}

Comment: I think you want to put that code in the question, here in the comment section it's unreadable.

Comment: and what happens if you call `waitForSignal()` in `run()` method?

Answer (score 1):

This code doesn't compile. Answer A means the code would throw InterruptedException while running. Your code has a compile error where obj.wait can throw InterruptedException and the exception isn't handled and the method is not declared as throwing it, so the class can't compile. So Answer A is not applicable here.

Of course the code from the question has the same problem. So the question seems flawed.

Once you fix the compile error, and move the waitForSignal call into the Thread's run method so that it gets called by the sd thread instead of the main thread, you should have something like:

```
public class ThreadStateProblem extends Thread {  
    public void run() {  
        waitForSignal();
    }  

    void waitForSignal() {
        Object obj = new Object();
        synchronized (Thread.currentThread()) {
            try {
                obj.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            obj.notify();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String []s) {  
        ThreadStateProblem sd =new ThreadStateProblem();
        sd.start();
    }    
}
```

then you should get the expected result:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at ThreadStateProblem.waitForSignal(ThreadStateProblem.java:10)
    at ThreadStateProblem.run(ThreadStateProblem.java:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will compile only if its surrounded with `try and catch` now coming on the explanation

-If the thread calling `wait()` does not own the lock on the object, a `IllegalMonitorStateException` will be thrown.

-Here we haven’t take lock for obj we are taking lock for current `thread` object.